# How do I find the most recently dated record for each ID in a set of IDs where any ID can have multiple records each for a particular date?

Tags: sql

I've got a data set that looks as follows:

[image]

The first column is an auto-increment primary key.  The second column is an ID number for whatever, maybe 3 rocks with IDs 1, 2 and 3 respectively.  (I probably should have used the standard customer and order example but oh well.)  The third column is a date when I threw the rock.  I track the date each time the rock is thrown, hence the multiple IDs (the second column) each with a throwing time.

I want a query to return the rock ID and most recent date for each ID.  The result of course would have a single record for each ID - the one with the latest access time.

I'm struggling with the possible combination of "DISTINCT", "TOP 1" and "GROUP BY" clauses that gives the result I want.

Comment: "I want a query to return the rock ID", what is rock ID?

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I was thinking database-independent since I felt the answer would use database-independent syntax.

Comment: @niktrs - The rock ID is an ID which uniquely identifies a rock, just like an SSN for a person or an ID that uniquely identifies an invoice.

Comment: You'll likely find that will be difficult, if not impossible depending on the functionality necessary.  ANSI isn't implemented wholesale -- it's piecemeal.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - The syntax given by @niktrs in the first query would work in any relational database I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, max(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

If you want also the autoincrement row id then

```
SELECT t1.rowid, t1.id, t1date
FROM table t1
JOIN (SELECT id,max(date) date FROM table1 t2 GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = t2.date
```

Comment: The `t2` alias should be applied to the entire subselect, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I love when there's a simple answer.  Am I reading properly that your second query is a self-join?  You specify a table name of "table" in the first FROM clause and then a table name of "table1" in the second FROM clause.  Are these the same table, or two tables, "table" and "table2"?

Comment: yes, it is the same table join by a subquery referencing again the same table